# MongoDB Spring inserting multiple documents in bulk is slow

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, mongo-java-driver, spring-repositories

I have a method that calls `MongoTemplate.insert(List<Object>)` to insert multiple objects inside my mongo database.

During performance testing, calling the method concurrently multiple times drastically increases the response times. For example, running `100 threads` each bulk-inserting `~100 documents` raises the response time for each thread to about `5 seconds`.

This doesn't seem right. Am I missing something?

Comment: What doesn't seem right about it? You're doing 100 inserts of a large number of documents simultaneously.

Comment: Is it expected that inserting 10.000 documents takes 5 seconds? Inserting them one by one instead in bulk doesn't degrade the performance by much (takes about double the time). Just trying to figure out if I'm doing something wrong.